# http.Redirect not working

Tags: http, go, header

i'm new to go, and i'm trying to do a redirect after login.

for the router, i'm using Mux:

```
router.HandleFunc("/login", pages.Login).Methods("POST")
```

and the Login func contains these lines:

```
if errorFlag {
    http.Redirect(rw, rq, "/", http.StatusNotAcceptable)
} else {
    http.Redirect(rw, rq, "/", http.StatusOK)
}
```

thing is, i'm getting the correct status according to the errorFlag, but the page is not redirected! the headers also seem to be set correctly ("Location:/")
but instead of redirecting, the page just stays blank and remains under "/login"

i've tested it on Chrome & FF.

these are the response headers:

```
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 14 Jan 2016 16:52:34 GMT
Location:localhost:8000/
Set-Cookie:user=MTQ1Mjc5MDM1N...; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 13 Feb 2016 16:52:34 UTC; Max-Age=2592000
```

anyone every encountered this before?

**Update**

As suggested below, this change works:

```
if errorFlag {
    http.Redirect(rw, rq, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
} else {
    http.Redirect(rw, rq, "/", http.StatusFound)
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a 3xx status code to redirect the client ([http.StatusFound](https://godoc.org/net/http#StatusFound), [http.StatusMovedPermanently](https://godoc.org/net/http#StatusMovedPermanently), http.StatusSeeOther, ...). The Location header is not sufficient to cause a redirect.

Comment: tried to do that, but it didn't seem to work. now instead of loading the login route, it just stays in the same page

Comment: could it be that it is caused because the Login function is set inside the pages package?

Comment: Confirm that the response has a 3xx status code.   The package organization in your application does not influence how a browser interprets a response.

Comment: sorry, i had remaining junk code left which caused it not to work. thanks for your help, works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to redirect POST method so neither 301 (StatusMovedPermanently) nor 302 (StatusFound) should work according to W3.org.

Try returning 303 (StatusSeeOther) if you want to redirect with GET method. Try returning status 307 (StatusTemporaryRedirect) if you want to redirect with the same method as in the request.

Details here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect